# Google Sheets Avg Query on empty columns (AVG_SUM_ONLY_NUMERIC)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Google Sheets average (avg) Query will fail with error `AVG_SUM_ONLY_NUMERIC` if any column in the dataset is empty. How you can overcome this?

Essentially, this occurs as the query is being run on a dynamically generated data set, therefore it's impossible to know what columns are empty beforehand. Moreover the query output "layout" must not change, so, if a column is empty, the query should return blank or 0 as for the faulty empty column.

Let's give it a look

**Scenario: a Google Sheet is being used to insert markings for students tests.**

When a single test is done by students, teacher assigns multiple grades for it. For instance, one marking for writing, one for comprehension, etc.

The sheet should finally build columns containing an average for all the markings assigned within the same date.

[image]

For instance, in the above sheet ([link here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1d2m5FiKwR1S0q749SPcHiNn_o04KXJZBoUF5FjFj9CY/edit#gid=929792899)), columns with markings given on December 16th (cols B,G,M,R,V) should be averaged in column AE.

Thanks to brilliant user [Marikamitsos](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/117311/marikamitsos), this is achieved with the following query in cell `AE4`:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(FILTER(B4:Z,B3:Z3=AE3)), 
 "select "&TEXTJOIN(",", 1, IF(LEN(A4:A), 
 "avg(Col"&ROW(A4:A)-ROW(A4)+1&")", )))&""),
 "select Col2")*1)
```

How does the above works?

1. Dataset is filtered by date
2. Filtered dataset is transposed and an `avg` Query is run on it
3. Result dataset is being queried again to easily filter out labels

All this works fine until a student has no markings for a given date, as occurs in cell `AG4`: student Bob has no markings for October's 28th test, and the query will throw an error `AVG_SUM_ONLY_NUMERIC`.

Could there be a way to insert a 0 in the filtered dataset `FILTER(B4:Z,B3:Z3=AE3)` so that ONLY empty rows will be set to 0? This would prevent the query to fail, while avoiding altering the dataset layout.
Or could there be a way to ignore zeroes in avg query?

NOTE: students cannot be graded with '0' when skipping a test!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this works

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(FILTER(B4:Z+0,B3:Z3=AG3)), "select "&TEXTJOIN(",", 1, IF(LEN(A4:A), "avg(Col"&ROW(A4:A)-ROW(A4)+1&")", )))&""),"select Col2")*1)
```

Comment: YES! Could you explain this?

Comment: Adding 0 to 'empty cells', will output 0 while keeping the other numbers intact. That way the AVG deals with numbers only. Also, numbers that are formatted as text will be converted to number format.

Comment: Fab! But how does the `Z+0` works? (BTW, do you offer freelance consulting? In case how can I add you to my Linkedin network?)

Comment: It's not really Z+0, but 0 added to contents of the range B4:Z. Left a link to my linkedin-profile in the sheet you shared.

Comment: Got it & sent connection request. Thanks!

Comment: could there be a way to ignore zeroes when calculating averages?